What is wrong with this proof of the Bolzano-Weiserstrass theorem?
I tried proving the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem before looking at the solution in my math textbook.
This is what I tried:
Take a bounded sequence $x_n$. Every sequence has a monotone subsequence according to the monotone subsequence theorem (I had proven this earlier). And since $x_n$ is bounded it then has to have a bounded monotone subsequence $x_m$. But a bounded monotone sequence must be convergent which means $x_m$ must be convergent.
But this proof seems way to simple to be correct and my book did the proof in a completely different way. So what is wrong with the proof I came up with?

It looks "simple" because you skipped (at least in this post) the difficult part, which is proving that $x_n$ has a monotone subsequence. Proving this is very nontrivial. Well, you wrote that you already proved it. Since you didn't post it here, we obviously can't know if your proof of this part is correct or not.

@Mark The proof of the monotone subsequence theorem I did checked out with my textbook. So I am pretty sure it is correct. Do you want me to post that proof as well?

If the question is whether your proof of BW theorem is correct assuming you already proved the monotone subsequence theorem, the answer is yes. But as Mark wrote: the monotone subsequence theorem is not trivial at all...though not particularly hard to prove.

Why are you asking if there is something wrong with your proof? Are you not sure of whether it is an acceptable proof?

@Plop yes, that is what I am asking

In my first calculus course, Bolzano-Weierstrass' theorem was proven this way. As said in the other comments, some proofs of a theorem are direct, and the difficulty is evenly distributed along it; some proofs use other theorems, and sometimes the difficulty is hidden in the proofs of the other theorems, that's it.

Ok then. DonAntonio answered: your proof is correct.

Try proving it also with Cantor's lemma, hint: the sequence is bounded therefore there is a closed interval containing it, divide in half inductively and use Cantor's lemma of nested intervals.

@ryaron that is what my textbook did. Allthough I found that version more difficult.
